# how do I go to next iteration of a for loop in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to read CSV files with different names. 
In my for loop, with different values of i, it checks for the file and import the file. There are some values of i, which is not associated with any file name.

Here, my question is how do I go to next iteration?
Thank you in advance!

```
for (i in 17:23)
{
  path= file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv"))
  if(!file.exists(path))
  data= read.table(path, header = F,    sep=",")
  datalist= list(data)
  else print(NA)
}





> for (i in 17:23)
+ {
+   path= file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv"))
+   if(!file.exists(path))
+   data= read.table(path, header = F,  sep=",")
+   datalist= list(data)
+ }
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '2017-02-23 19_00_00/Registrations.csv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: it's not clear what is the desired outcome, if the desired outcome is to save all the tables in the object `datalist` then you need to iterate over that. please clarify.

Comment: Hi,

I want to list all the files.  I think the problem is with missing files with i values.
For example, the for loop runs perfect for i= 17,18 but there is no folder for i=19 and then it quits

Comment: > for (i in 17:23)
+ {
+   path= file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv"))
+   if(!file.exists(path))
+   data= read.table(path, header = F, sep=",")
+   datalist= list(data)
+ }
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '2017-02-23 19_00_00/Registrations.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: The answer to your direct question is `next`. But `paste` and listing files are both vectorized, so the better way to go `paste` the potential file names and check if the exist before the loop, and then only loop over the ones that exist.

Comment: You are overwriting `datalist` each time.  Set `datalist <- list()` at the start, and then `datalist <- c(datalist,data)` inside the loop.  `datalist` will then be a list of your read-in dataframes.

Comment: I can not check the manually for existence. there is more than thousand folders :(

Answer (score 6):

You could use `next`:

```
datalist = list()
for (i in 17:23) {
  file = paste0("2017-02-23 ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv")
  path = file.path(file)
  if(!file.exists(path)) {
     next
  }
  data = read.table(path, header = F, sep = ",")
  datalist[[file]] = data
}
```

I have

- used `next` to skip iterations where the file doesn't exist
- initialized the list and added files by name to the list
- gotten rid of the useless `print(NA)` line.

But this does the same thing more efficiently (and I would say, more clearly):

```
paths = file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ", 17:23, "_00_00/Registrations.csv"))
extant_paths = paths[file.exists(paths)]
datalist = lapply(extant_paths, read.table, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

`paste`, `file.path`, and `file.exists` are all vectorized, so it will be easier and faster to use those all at once. The only operation that needs to be in the loop is `read.csv`. Here we use `lapply` as a convenient syntax instead of a `for` loop - it saves us needing to initialize the `list` and assign elements to it manually.

Comment: Great!! 
the 1st code works perfect.
Thank you so much. :)

I am not able to do read.csv
my rJava dose not work properly

Comment: You can still use `read.table` with `lapply`. And `read.csv` has nothing to do with `rJava`. `read.csv` is a base function that is just a small wrapper around `read.table`.

Comment: Hi, I need one more help.

I am running for loop. I have three for loops in one chunk. 


    for(k in 01:12){
      for (j in 01:31) {
        for (i in 00:23) {
          file = paste0("2017-", k ,"-", j ," ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv") 

In this for loop i, j and k's are taking values like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,....so on

I need to get these i, j and k's like 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12...and so on

How do I format these i,j and k's to get desired 2 digit values??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sounds like a new question. Just ask a new question. Or search a little on stack overflow for "R print leading zeros".